# gopls: Message: no object found for ident ... Go Problem with methods on C Structs

Tags: go, cgo, gopls

[Code Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlJI0.png)

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person {
    char* name;
    int age;
} Person;
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func (p *C.Person) PrintName() {
    name := C.GoString(p.name)
    fmt.Println(name)
}

func main() {
    name := C.CString("John")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(name))

    age := C.int(30)

    cPerson := C.Person{
        name: name,
        age:  age,
    }

    person := C.Person(cPerson)
    person.PrintName()
}
```

The above program runs and compiles perfectly fine. However, while using Code Editors (Vs Code or GoLand) you can see the above issue. It doesn't recognise PrintName() function. Moreover, if I run `gopls check main.go` I get the following response:
`main.go:34:9-18: person.PrintName undefined (type _Ctype_struct_Person has no field or method PrintName)`

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? Clearly the issue is with gopls. Code refactoring can resolve this issue but it is not a suitable option for existing large code base.